# How to catch syntax errors in Java if I am compiling the code through the PHP exec() method?

Tags: java, php, compilation

The code in PHP using the exec() command looks like this:

`exec('javac -classpath dir test.java');`

I am wondering how I can catch syntax errors that exist within the test.java file.

Comment: By compiling test.java probably

Comment: If you can get what would otherwise be printed to the console, that's what you want. You should give us an example of what you've tried so far and an example of what you mean, so you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Append `2>&1` to the end of your command

```
exec('javac -classpath dir test.java 2>&1',$op);
var_dump($op);
```

Here `2` is stderr and `1` is stdout

Answer (score 1):

If you use all 3 `exec` arguments, you'll see the output:

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

exec() executes the given command.
Parameters ¶

command

    The command that will be executed.
output

    If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().
return_var

    If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.
```